# Joins using Sub Queries

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I have two tables named "Book" and "Author." The attributes for the "Book" table are: **PK- Book_Num, Book_Title, Book_Year, Book_Cost, Book_Subject.** The attributes for the "Author" table are **PK- Au_ID, Au_Fname, Au_Lname.** These two tables have a M:N relationship with each other and the bridge table between them is named "Writes" and it has a composite primary key from the two tables made up  of **Book_Num and Au_ID.** Here's my question: I want to write a query to display the Au_ID, Au_Fname, Au_Lname for all authors that have never written a book with the subject "Programming" and order the results by Au_Lname. How would I go about doing this with a sub-query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
SELECT A.Au_ID, A.Au_Fname, A.Au_Lname FROM Author A 
  JOIN Writes W ON A.Au_ID = W.Au_ID
  JOIN Book B ON B.Book_Num = W.Book_Num
  WHERE A.Au_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT A.Au_ID FROM Author A 
      JOIN Writes W ON A.Au_ID = W.Au_ID
      JOIN Book B ON B.Book_Num = W.Book_Num
      WHERE B.Book_Subject = 'Programming'
  )
  ORDER BY A.Au_Lname ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I just had to add the Unique to the Au_ID to get the query I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want better performance,you can use "NOT EXISTS" to get the data you want.

```
SELECT Au_ID, Au_Fname, Au_Lname FROM Author
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT A.Au_ID FROM Author A 
    JOIN Writes W ON A.Au_ID = W.Au_ID
    JOIN Book B ON B.Book_Num = W.Book_Num
    WHERE B.Book_Subject = 'Programming'
    AND Author.Au_ID = A.Au_ID 
)
ORDER BY Au_Lname ASC
```